# google chart problem

Tags: gwt, charts, google-visualization

I am using google gwt visualizations chart in gwt application.

I want to show only 2d chart.

but the following problems come.

.

In colums chart

it show scale like 0.0 , 10.4 ,40.5 ....

how to customize the Change scale of the graph. scale should uniform . for example  if highest number is more than 400 then it should be 0 , 100, 200 ,300 and if it is 90 then it should be 0 ,20,40,60,80

in piechart

it shows percentage on the slice  want to show the actual value.

Thanks In advance

Comment: Could you post the options used to build your column chart please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the column chart, I've never seen that behavior. Maybe it comes from the way you build your data ?

In contrast, about your piechart's question, if you have the last version of gwt visualization (1.1.1), in the PieChart.PieOptions class, there is a method named `setPieSliceText(String text)`.

This method takes 4 possible parameters :

- percentage : to display the percentage value
- value : to display the quantitive value of the slice
- label : to display the name of the slice
- none : I think it's obvious ;)

If you don't have the last version and if you can't make the upgrade, just extend the static class PieOptions and implement the native method by yourself.

I hope it helps!